# angularjs ui-router syntax

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a datatable, when I select an element, I have an edit button that appears that need to have the correct edit url, here what I have done:

```
// this is triggered on select AND unselect (multiselect = false)
function onRowSelectionChanged(row, evt) {
            if (row.isSelected) {
                vm.feed = row.entity;
            } else {
                delete vm.feed;
            }
            vm.selected = row.isSelected;
        }

// this is the watcher that updates my button
$scope.$watch(function () {
            return vm.selected;
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue === oldValue) {
                return;
            }
            if (newValue) {
                vm.actions.push({state: 'app.feeds.edit({feedId: ' + vm.feed.id + '})', icon: 'pencil'});
            } else {
                vm.actions.splice(-1);
            }
        });
```

My question is about this:

`vm.actions.push({state: 'app.feeds.edit({feedId: ' + vm.feed.id + '})', icon: 'pencil'});`

Is this a clean way of interpolating the value, or can I do better ? as the Feed is bound to the vm, how comes I cannot do this:

`vm.actions.push({state: 'app.feeds.edit({feedId: vm.feed.id})', icon: 'pencil'});`

If I write this last piece of code, I always get `feeds//edit`

Answer (score 0):

Because the handlebars {{ }} are used in the html or templates.

if you want to add a value in a string with js you need to escape it with and concatenate it.

This is just how you can inject values into strings